# Replacing recursion with iteration

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

I have a recursive function which I need to convert to an iterative function but I am quite stuck. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

```
f :: Int -> Int
f(0) = 5
f(1) = 8
f(2) = 3
f(n) = (f(n-3)) * (f(n-1))
```

Cheers

Comment: and why you think Java Tag is required in your post ?

Comment: It is important to understand the difference between recursion and dynamic programming.

Comment: @NeerajJain sorry I will remove it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet should do the trick:

```
int output[1000];
output[0] = 5;
output[1] = 8;
output[2] = 3;

for (int i=3; i < 1000; ++i) {
    output[i] = output[i-3] * output[i-1];
}
```

Bonus: Implementing your function non-recursively in this manner is called **dynamic programming**.

Comment: thanks for this but I am looking for a method that works for all n>0?

Comment: Actually yeah if I replace the 1000 by n it should work. Thanks I will accept your answer now

Comment: This is just rolling the stack into an array - it's still essentially the same function as the recursive solution except that it uses heap instead of stack.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I disagree with you.  A recursive solution would involve **many** more function calls for N=1000.  My solution only involves 1000 iterations.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - That is a good point - it also uses 1000 integers. You are `Memoizing` the first n solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it works. Essentially it keeps the most recent 3 numbers and walks them upwards until we hit n.

```
public int rf(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 5
            : n == 1 ? 8
                    : n == 2 ? 3
                            : rf(n - 3) * rf(n - 1);
}

public int nrf(int n) {
    int[] v = {5, 8, 3};
    int x = n == 0 ? 5
            : n == 1 ? 8
                    : n == 2 ? 3
                            : 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        x = v[0] * v[2];
        v[0] = v[1];
        v[1] = v[2];
        v[2] = x;
    }
    return x;
}

public void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(rf(i) + " = " + nrf(i));
    }
}
```

Correctly prints:

```
5 = 5
8 = 8
3 = 3
15 = 15
120 = 120
360 = 360
5400 = 5400
648000 = 648000
233280000 = 233280000
1286582272 = 1286582272
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but tim's answer is easier and scalable to any function.

Comment: @kabeerv - Tim's solution could be very memory hungry for larger n. I essentially do the same but I just keep the last three entries of his potentially huge array so I am not memory sensitive at all.

Comment: @kabeerv - This is also scalable to any function - the function implemented here is encoded with the `x = v[0] * v[2];` which is the equivalent of your `rf(n - 3) * rf(n - 1)`.

Comment: I didnt mean to offend, I appreciate your help and have upvoted the answer but I just wanted to know the concept behind doing something like this and tim's solution seems to work for any case without much effort which is what I was looking for. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: @kabeerv - Not offended - just making sure you understand that this is much less brittle than a recursive solution or one that pulls the stack into the heap.